# Firebase deploy errors : Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

This is my first flutter project, I recently faced a problem using firebase deploy command and I want to deploy my flutter web project on Mac.

```
i  deploying database, functions, hosting, extensions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

/bin/sh: --: invalid option
Usage:  /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
        /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
        --debug
        --debugger
        --dump-po-strings
        --dump-strings
        --help
        --init-file
        --login
        --noediting
        --noprofile
        --norc
        --posix
        --protected
        --rcfile
        --restricted
        --verbose
        --version
        --wordexp
Shell options:
        -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
        -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2
```

It looks like the error is occurring during the execution of the linting command.? i have try to install npm command but the question still here.

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 3.13.9 on channel stable at /Users/gerald/Desktop/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d211f42860 (3 weeks ago), 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
    • Engine revision 0545f8705d
    • Dart version 3.1.5
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gerald/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/gerald/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.76.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.123

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is some issue with the lint file, I can't say what happens exactly, but if you are sure that your syntax is ok, you can try to remove the field predeploy in firebase.json

"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint"
]